# Example code to read device ID of MachXo2 with FTDI -JTAG

Tags: fpga, software, jtag, ftdi, lattice

In my project I am working on MachX02 programming with FTDI master using JTAG functionality. I am trying to read device ID of MachX02, but not working, here is my sample code to read device ID of MachX02:

```
cmd_buffer[0] = 0xE0;
cmd_buffer[1] = (byte)((operand & 0xFF0000) >> 16);
cmd_buffer[2] = (byte)((operand & 0x00FF00) >> 8);
cmd_buffer[3] = (byte)(operand & 0x0000FF);

JTAG_WriteRead(fthandle, false, 32, cmd_buffer, 4, m_readbuffer, ref operand, RUN_TEST_IDLE_STATE);
```

Where I went wrong could not able to identify, for MachX02 before sending device ID opcode, do I need to send any another opcode?
Please help to overcome this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error? Look up the IDCODE instruction for the MachXO2, shift that into the IR and then do a 32-bit DR shift to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what MachXO2 device you are using, but I pulled the BSDL files of a couple of them at random. The IDCODE opcode appears to be '11100000', or 0xE0.

I'm also not sure what FTDI library you're using, but I'll assume you're using a FTDI FT2232H or similar that is capable of acting as a JTAG master via MPSSE functionality or similar.

To read the IDCODE, you basically have to do the following:

1. JTAG Reset (put chain into known state) -- can be 5 TCKs with TMS held high
2. Load IR 0xE0 (8-bit IR Shift)
3. Perform a 32-bit DR shift to read out the IDCODE.

That's all there is to it -- I don't think the part needs to be in any particular state to support the IDCODE instruction. An ISC (IEEE 1532) instruction to read the USERCODE, possibly, but I also that's unlikely -- you should be able to read both with ease.

I Googled the function you're using (please add more detail to your questions in the future), and I think you're calling it incorrectly, since you appear to be writing to a data register. I *think* you want:

```
JTAG_WriteRead(fthandle, true, 8, 0xE0, 1, m_IRbuffer, m_numBytes, RUN_TEST_IDLE_STATE);
JTAG_WriteRead(fthandle, false, 32, 0x00000000, 4, m_DRbuffer, m_numBytes, RUN_TEST_IDLE_STATE);
```

Where m_IRbuffer is a buffer of size 1 byte, and m_DRbuffer is of size 4 bytes (32 bits), and m_numBytes can be a 1 byte char of some type. The first command should load 0xE0 into the IR. The second should shift in 32-bits of 0 into the IDCODE DR register, and you should get back the IDCODE in m_DRbuffer.

As an aside, if you're having trouble with this amount of low-level work, I would suggest using urjtag or a similar software library to read the information you need.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer...now i able to get device ID..Thanks once again...   i am new to this JTAG communication..now to Erase Flash UFM and SRAM ...i have to send Enable configuration Offline Opcode [0xC6] followed with 3 bytes operands [08 00 00]....opcode command needs to send IR register and please tell me which register to send Operands...similarly for Erase also opcode [0x0E] could send to IR register and Operands[0E 00 00] while i am trying to send on both DR as well as IR..not working ..please give some Snippet code how to send Operands to Erase .....Thanks in advance .